# Conditional aggregation in a window function: gaps and island problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, azure-data-factory, window-functions

I'm trying to create a timeline of events, some of which are duplicate:

*Source data*

| user_id | question | opinion | last_modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-11 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-12 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 0 | 2019-03-13 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-14 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 0 | 2019-03-16 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 0 | 2019-03-17 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 0 | 2019-03-18 |

Imagine being asked the same question over random periods of time - e.g. *"Do you agree or disagree with a statement?"* The goal of my work is to describe the periods of support - for how much time did a response remain 1 or 0:

*Target table*

| user_id | question | opinion | from | until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-11 | 2019-03-13 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 0 | 2019-03-13 | 2019-03-14 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-14 | 2019-03-16 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 0 | 2019-03-16 | *NULL* |

The last "until" entry should be a *NULL*, as that's the last measurement and we do not expect changes since.

I've tried a basic window function with a row offset, however that does not take duplicates into account and just creates multiple entries with incorrect from/until dates:

*consecutive duplicates example - undesired behaviour*

| user_id | question | opinion | from | until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-11 | 2019-03-12 |
| 21175381 | 13 | 1 | 2019-03-12 | 2019-03-13 |

I'm building this in ADF, so any ideas on how to get it working either through pure SQL or ADF transformations are welcome! Thanks a lot in advance - for your time, effort and knowledge!

Comment: This doesn't look like conditional aggregation and more like a gaps and island problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Larnu, was unaware of the gaps and island problem - sure seems like it, will look into solutions.

Comment: Why do you want the until value to contain the 1st date of the next opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions to create the groups where the value of `opinion` has not changed and group by user_id, question to get the min date of each group inside a CTE.
Then do  a self join of the CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT user_id, question, grp, opinion, MIN(last_modified) [from]
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN opinion <> prev_opinion THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, question ORDER BY last_modified) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *, LAG(opinion, 1, ~opinion) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, question ORDER BY last_modified) prev_opinion
      FROM tablename
    ) t  
  ) t  
  GROUP BY user_id, question, opinion, grp
)
SELECT c1.user_id, c1.question, c1.opinion, c1.[from], c2.[from] until
FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2
ON c2.user_id = c1.user_id AND c2.question = c1.question AND c2.grp = c1.grp + 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0ce7a1d89b5078eeeb4bc771ee99aa6f).

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked!

A minor modification I did was `MAX(cast(opinion as int))` on line 2 - the source is bit, and MIN does not work with bits.

Comment: @d1sh4 fine if it worked. Actually it is not needed. You can just select opinion if you add it in the group by clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=68ceb6485772546447ad0f06f528c87a

Comment: Don't understand why you need the self-join, just use `LEAD`

Comment: @d1sh4 if opinion is BIT I made a change: `LAG(opinion, 1, ~opinion)` instead of `LAG(opinion, 1, -1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to solve this problem uses `lag()` to keep the first record when something changes.  No aggregation or `join`s are needed.

Then `lead()` to get the next value:

```
select user_id, question, opinion,
       last_modified as from,
       lead(last_modified) over (partition by user_id, question order by last_modified) as until
from (select t.*,
             lag(opinion) over (partition by user_id, question order by last_modified) as prev_opinion
      from t
     ) t
where prev_opinion <> opinion or prev_opinion is null;
```

I think this is the simplest way to get the results you want.  It should also have the best performance.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=341acd2aebb7c0c0a44218e72ca10181) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Elegant @GordonLinoff.  Upvote from me.  I created a [simple test rig](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/dee57650739c4c3c492252c5d835d624) with half a million records which on my local 2019 in a few mins.  Yours was the fastest option, mine a close second.  Interestingly the accepted answer is the worst performing by a long way and all queries run slower with any kind of indexes on the temp tables.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@forpas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68920122/), **you can remove the self-join** by using `LEAD`.

```sql
SELECT
  user_id,
  question,
  grp,
  opinion,
  MIN(last_modified) [from],
  LEAD(MIN(last_modified)) OVER
    (PARTITION BY user_id, question ORDER BY grp) [until]
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN opinion <> prev_opinion THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, question ORDER BY last_modified) grp
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          LAG(opinion, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, question ORDER BY last_modified) prev_opinion
        FROM tablename
    ) t  
) t  
GROUP BY user_id, question, opinion, grp;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76ec919db731c204ed04819101178680)